# Webbrowser SetAttribute not working (Password Field)

Tags: c#, passwords, browser, setattribute

tried to write a program which logs me in automatically in a webbrowser in c#. This is the code i use at the moment for this purpose:

```
HtmlElementCollection pageTextElements = loginBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
        foreach (HtmlElement element in pageTextElements)
        {
            if (element.Name.Equals("username"))
                element.SetAttribute("value", this.UserName);
            if (element.Name.Equals("password"))
                element.SetAttribute("value", this.Password);
        }
```

It fills in the Username, but not the password? ):
Googled around but there are only a few people which started topic to which no one ever replied. /:

hopefully someone can help me.
this is the source auf the password field:

```
<input type="password" value="" maxlength="50" size="25" name="password" class="bginput">
```

Comment: @Adam Maras Thanks for clarifying. Removing my answer, as I have no advice for that.

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint on the line that sets the attribute of the password field, just to see if it even gets hit?

Comment: yes, i did. it gets hit, executes, but simply doesn't put the password in the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wait until the document updating has been completed.  `DocumentCompleted` event method.

If you want to see what is going on create a form with a `Panel` on top and a `WebBrowser` on the bottom.  Add 3 `TextBoxes`, a `Button` and another `TextBox`.  The `OnClick` method of the following box do the following:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById(this.textBox1.Text).SetAttribute(this.textBox2.Text, this.textBox3.Text);
this.textBox4.Text = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById(this.textBox1.Text).GetAttribute(this.textBox2.Text);
```

You'll see that your `Password` box on you form populates correctly.

Wayne

Answer (score 5):

None of the above worked for me,  I could call setAttribute() on the username textbox in the DocumentCompleted() event handler but not the password text box. I eventually got it to work by:

```
HtmlElementCollection inputs = doc.GetElementsByTagName("input");
HtmlElement usr = inputs.GetElementsByName("username")[0];
usr.setAttribute("value", strUsername);

HtmlElement pwd = inputs.GetElementsByName("password")[0];
pwd.GotFocus += new HtmlElementEventHandler(pwd_GotFocus);
pwd.Focus();
```

Then in onFocus handler:

```
void pwd_GotFocus(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
{
    HtmlElement pwd = (HtmlElement)sender;
    pwd.SetAttribute("value", strPassword);
}
```

I have no idea why this works and the other doesn't.  I tried only changing the password just in case the document change from setting the username interfered with it. I even went to far as to create another WebBrowser control, then took the DocumentText from the source, did a find and replace setting the password value in the raw html before setting the DocumentText on the second WebBrowser and it again did not set the value properly.

I would love to know a cleaner solution if anyone has one

Comment: It bloody works for me too! Been trying all sort of ways.. this step seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

try setting the innerText property like this, it works for me (vb.net):

```
Dim txtPassword As HtmlElement = browser.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPassword")

txtPassword.InnerText = "123456"
```

Comment: Solved the problem by writing all elements into a string and change there the &password= to &password=thepass ;)
works now, thanks everyone (: