# C# SetAttribute Value to ElementID isn't working?

Tags: c#

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("firstName").SetAttribute("value", firstName); 

webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("lastName").SetAttribute("value", lastName); 

webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("userName").SetAttribute("value", email); 

webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("value", "Psu123"); 

webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("passwordConfirmation").SetAttribute("value", "Psu123");
```

Everything get filled except for this line: `webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("value", "Psu123");`

Language using is C# inspect element link below. http://gyazo.com/964291abb825eac4ea8aae002d7ce382

How come everything get filled up except for the "password"

Comment: When are you doing this? It should be in the `DocumentCompleted` event if it isn't already.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [Webbrowser SetAttribute not working (Password Field)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269769/webbrowser-setattribute-not-working-password-field)

As Equalsk mentioned, ensure you're setting your values in the WebBrowser DocumentCompleted Event